# Windows 8 privilege issue

Tags: windows, windows-8, administrator, privileges

I'm trying to delete some folder on windows 8 but I can't he show this message `You should have administrator privilege to delete this folder` my Windows account is admin and i got all privilege on this folder for As Adminstrator.

Comment: tried to `takeown` ?

Comment: What directory is it? i.e. Is it a folder you have created?

Comment: it's windows.old directory It contain my Windows 7 after upgrade :D

Comment: Typical case of an X-Y problem. [There's a better way](http://superuser.com/questions/515784/deleting-windows-old-folder) (duplicate).