# Does Windows still keeps old versions of files after each update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

Does Windows still keeps old versions of files after each update or remove all old redundant files?

Comment: You have your answer [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/266337/what-should-i-remove-in-disk-cleanup-on-windows/).

Comment: Yes it keeps them in case you need to remove a particular update, you can however remove them using disk cleanup as suggested by "guest vm" above.

Comment: but disk cleanup freezes when cleaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Windows Update replaces a file, the previous version is not saved in the
Recycle Bin, so no redundant files.

When one installs a new Windows version, or if you do an
[In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
the old Windows files go into the folder `Windows.old`.
However, most of them are deleted after 28 days.

Comment: What about system files (files of various system processes) like 7-8 version of lot of exe, like in  Windows 7 for compatability, etc other purposes, do Windows 10 still do that?

Comment: For `Windows.old` you will find more information in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1210475/8672).

Comment: The old files are saved somewhere or uninstalling them wouldn't be an option.  Also disk cleanup wouldn't be offering to delete 1GB+ of windows update files.

Comment: These are the files that will be used to undo the updates, same as Windows.old can be used for 28 days to roll back to a previous version of Windows. We don't know the rules of Microsoft about how long these files are kept, and if you clean these files out then you just cannot undo these updates, no other problem. In any case, the files are kept in a proprietary format of Microsoft, and that format may change after a major update of Windows and without explanation.